# MYSQLi num_rows always returns 0

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use MySQLi with my website and I am writting a login script. Now i have a problem with num_rows always returning value 0

So this is my code

```
if($query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 'password','ban' FROM users WHERE 'username'=? LIMIT 1")){
            $query->bind_param('s', $username);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($db_password,$ban);                 
            $query->store_result();
            $query->fetch();
            $numrows = $query->num_rows;        

            if($numrows == 1){
                if($ban == 0)
                {
                    if($db_password == $password)
                    {
                        $_SESSION['login'] = 'ok';
                        //$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                        //$_SESSION['realname'] = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/","",$realname);
                        header("Location: /ematura/index.php");
                        $query->close();
                    }else{
                    die("Napaka");
                    }
                }else{
                    die("Račun zaklenjen");
                }
            }
```

My question is, why is num_rows always 0, even though the user exists?

Comment: I don't see you checking any of the queries for failure.  How do you know the `->execute()` succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names should not be enclosed with single or double quotes, instead you can use backticks (`)

```
SELECT `password`,`ban` FROM users WHERE `username`=? LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Better still, don't quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: @AndyLester: I suggest to add your comment to my answer :)

Comment: +1 to Akam's answer about using correct quotes, and +1 to Andy's advice to avoid using reserved words as table names & column names. But delimited identifiers are also needed if you use international characters in identifiers.  It's totally legitimate to use special characters if you speak that language! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are binding correctly, try changing to: `$query->bind_param(1, $username);`

From: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

> public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed
>   &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed
>   $driver_options ]]] )
>
> **parameter**
>
> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named
>   placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a
>   prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the
>   1-indexed position of the parameter.